# javax.swing.Timer vs java.util.Timer

Tags: java

I heard  all `javax.swing` classes should only be used if Iam actually building a `Swing GUI`.
I would like to use `javax.swing.Timer` without `GUI` in order to create timer loop. Does it mean that without GUI shall i use `java.util.Timer`?

Is it big error to use `javax.swing.Timer` without `GUI` ? Can it cause some performance error or slowdown?

What are some approaches to creating a loop that will run passively or without halting the main thread?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is not recommended since it is another dependency you need.

You should try to have as few as possible dependencies. If `java.util.Timer` is something that satisfies your needs you definitely should choose this one.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it big error to use javax.swing.Timer without GUI ? Can it cause
>   some performance error or slowdown?

No, It is not a big error. But , the `ActionEvents` associated with the `javax.swing.Timer` won't fire if there is no `non-daemon` thread running in the application . If no `non-daemon` thread is running in application then the program will exit gracefully without making the `javax.swing.Timer` to execute associated `actionPerformed` method. But GUI causes the JVM to hang up and let the `Timer` to execute the `actionPerformed` method. 
In case you are not using GUI, make sure that there is some `non-daemon` thread running in application.

> What are some approaches to creating a loop that will run passively or
>   without halting the main thread?

You can use [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for this purpose. But now [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) has provided a lot of enrich set of APIs to perform concurrent tasks. So , now you should move on to [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) API for this purpose.

Comment: Well, i have java 1.7.0 and i use javax.swing.Timer in application with no GUI whatsoever, and it works perfectly, just add java.awt.event.ActionListener and its k.

Comment: @kajacx: Yeah you are right in your words that there is no error if `javax.swing.Timer` is used to with non-GUI application. There is absolutely **no Error** in doing this. But what I wanted to emphasize that the `ActionEvent` related to `javax.swing.Timer` wouldn't fire if there is no `non-daemon` thread running in application. And GUI causes the JVM to hang up till all the GUIs are not disposed.

Comment: Yea, that daemon thing is pretty annoying